# Is it a good idea to store device identifier in keychain for iOS app

Tags: uuid, keychain, mac-address

As Apple Deprecated uniqueIdentifier in iOS 5, I was thinking to use CFUUIDCreate function to create a UUID. But when I call CFUUIDCreate everytime , it creates new UUID. So my plan was to use CFUUIDCreate when app launches for very first time & store it in NSUserDefaults. So if user deletes or reinstalls the app , UUID will be delted. So I was wondering if I can store generated UUID in Keychain. So my questions are

1) If I delete the app , then UUID will be present in keychain or not ?
2) Is it a good idea to store it in keychain ?

I have take a look at [gekitz](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5)

But I want to use only MAC Address of device  then does Apple allow developer to retrive MAC Address of device?

Any knid of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

yes, but also set

```
[keychain setObject:(id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccessible];
```